# What is the nearest Ford circle for any point in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: discrete-geometry, continued-fractions, circle-packing

I want to draw [Ford circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_circle) within a "distance Estimated system" (ray marching). Therefore, given a point $(x,y)$ from $\mathbb R^2$, I need the shortest distance to any circle with center $(p/q,1/2q^2)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ with radius $(1/2q^2)$ for coprime integers $p$, $q$.
It should be somehow possible to calculate (or at least approximate) with … maybe a continued fraction approximation of $x$?

[image: Pictures of Ford circles]

Comment: What is a distance estimated system?  Googling yields only [distance estimated fractals](http://blog.hvidtfeldts.net/index.php/2011/06/distance-estimated-3d-fractals-part-i); is that related?  Also, is it clear that there is a *unique* closest Ford circle to every point?

Comment: yea, that link explains it. For sure there is almost anywhere a closest circle. however if tehre are more then one then at least the distance will be unique :-)

Comment: When p/q is the continued fraction of x which is approximated up to q>1/y then i always find the biggest circle **below** (x,y). Now i still need to find the bigger neighbour circles - which are also neigbours of p/q in the Farey Sequence F_q